# Teach Notepad++ to fold new multiline comment (R)

Tags: r, notepad++

Can I teach Notepad++ that it should apply a fold whenever it sees a multi-line comment, where comments start with the hash mark and multi-line comments are hash marks on consecutive lines?

```
# This is a comment
# It continues on the next line
# and the next
# I want to fold this block
```

**Edit**
I submitted a fix to the R lexer to support multi-line comments.  It includes the fix to source as well as a compiled SciLexer.dll for those who are eager to use this feature.  Simply replace SciLexer.dll in the NPP folder with the one attached to the bug:
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3485870&group_id=95717&atid=612385

Comment: Close voter: you don't vote to close this as too localized just because you don't use Notepad++. I'm pretty sure this would be applicable to a reasonable niche of Notepad++ users out there.

Comment: I'm certainly eager to see something like this.  @SFun28: Are you looking at using this for R?

Comment: Yup.  I use NPP as my R editor, but the inability to fold function headers makes browsing a .R file a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @Iterator - I edited my post with a link to the fix (including the binary which you can drop into your NPP program folder).  Let me know if it worked for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested your multi-line comment with notepad++ 5.9.8 and it correctly fold as a single entity as long as there is a non-comment line between the comment groups and that the language selected has comments starting with '#' (eg: sh).

EDIT:

This seem to be language specific.

I've looked at the xml files that configure the behavior of notepad++ and it seem that this mechanic is hardcoded inside the program.

EDIT2:

The author of the question has just added comment folding support for the R languange!

Comment: It seems that this folding only works for PERL and BASH(Shell) language choices. Other languages which also use `#` for comments (Python, Ruby, PowerShell, PHP) do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Can I replace a language's comment style with the sh-style?  In that way, I can get the comment folding with the non-comment-language-specific syntax highlighting?  Specifically, the comment-folding would be a great feature for the R language.  Can I tell notepad++ to "borrow" the treatment of comments in Shell, but keep everything else from R?

Comment: Or maybe I can just request the author to make the change

Comment: @sfun i've tryed to massage the xml's and it seem to be hardcoded, sorry.

Comment: thanks for trying!  I'm going to attempt a fix to source and attach as feature request on the SourceForge site.

Comment: @Gigi - fixed!  see post above.